# Question on bounty

Tags: discussion, bounty

I set a bounty for my question last week and it will end after 23 hours more. However, there is no answer for my question yet, just only comment.

I was noticed that if I do not set a bounty for an answer then it will be given automatically half of what I set. As I said, there is no answer for my question.

What will happen in my case?

Comment: You ever wondered how the system can affording giving all this reputation to people? It's from bounties which disappear like that...

Answer (score 7, accepted):

From the [FAQ](https://math.stackexchange.com/faq#bounty):

> If you do not award your bounty within 7 days (plus the grace period), the highest voted answer created after the bounty started with at least 2 upvotes will be awarded half the bounty amount. If there's no answer meeting that criteria, the bounty is not awarded to anyone.

If no one answers your question, the bounty is not awarded to anyone (it sort of just evaporates into the system).